# Get font face under cursor in Emacs

Tags: emacs, fonts, emacs-faces

I've been developing my own custom color theme, and it'd be really useful if I could get a list of font-faces affecting the text under the cursor.

Something like Textmate's show current scope command.

That would save me the trouble of doing M-x customize-face and looking through available options, guessing at which one affects the current word I'm on.

Any ideas?

Comment: In case you're looking for the same functionality using the **mouse** cursor (if, e.g., you cannot get `point` on the text in question), see: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35449/13444

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can define `what-face` with this code:

```lisp
(defun what-face (pos)
  (interactive "d")
  (let ((face (or (get-char-property (pos) 'read-face-name)
                  (get-char-property (pos) 'face))))
    (if face (message "Face: %s" face) (message "No face at %d" pos))))
```

After that,

```
M-x what-face
```

will print the face found at the current point.

(Thanks to [thedz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84380/thedz) for pointing out that `what-face` wasn’t built in.)

Comment: This ignores faces set as text properties. If enable `hl-line-mode` you will only see `hl-line` as the face, not the other faces. Consider https://gist.github.com/Wilfred/f7d61b7cdf9fdbb1d11c

Comment: [Karl Fogel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/247145/karl-fogel) pointed out a bug in this code [in a separate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20844370/578288): the output message says it’s describing the face at the `pos` parameter, but the reading of the face is actually done at `(point)` rather than at `pos`.

Comment: This doesn't works, you can use "M-x describe-face" instead.

Comment: `pos` is not a function; in order make the snippet work, you should replace `(pos)` with `pos` on lines 3 and 4

Answer (score 194):

`what-cursor-position` with a prefix argument shows the face under point, among other information.

Keyboard shortcut is **C-u C-x =**

Example output (the face property is shown in the last paragraph):

```
             position: 5356 of 25376 (21%), column: 4
            character: r (displayed as r) (codepoint 114, #o162, #x72)
    preferred charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x72
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, L:Left-to-right (strong), a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
          buffer code: #x72
            file code: #x72 (encoded by coding system undecided-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    nil:-apple-Monaco-medium-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x55)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LATIN SMALL LETTER R
  general-category: Ll (Letter, Lowercase)
  decomposition: (114) ('r')

There are text properties here:
  face                 org-level-2
  fontified            t

[back]
```

Comment: Which invokes `what-cursor-position`.

Comment: hmmm, sometimes it invokes what-cursor-position, sometimes it displays a list of buffer properties (including font). If I get the former behaviour, moving the cursor and repeating brings on the latter.

Comment: I am so happy I found this, with some unknown combinations of the commands and keystrokes I got `emacs` to display how I liked it and didn't how to get it back in my next restart

Comment: It shows the font name on Emacs GUI. On terminal, Emacs is not responsible for setting the font and therefore such information is not available when one does `C-u C-x =` in Emacs running on the terminal, like `emacs -nw file.txt`.

Comment: Cheesy mnemonic "user experience equals"... *groan*

Answer (score 74):

M-x describe-face

Comment: This also includes the nice link making it possible to customize the face under cursor immediately

Comment: This works well most of the time, but sometimes for reasons I can't figure out sometimes it doesn't suggest the face I'm looking for.  For example in eshell when there is ansi color it just says "default".

Comment: This shows me a prompt where I can enter something. What would I need to enter, in order to describe the font under cursor?

Comment: This worked for me to customize code block fonts in org-mode. @Zelphir, the text before the prompt showed the face, in my case at least. You might just hit `return`. For example my result read `Describe face (default ‘org-block-background’): `.

Answer (score 8):

Trey's what face is on the right track.  It led me to an email on a mailing list that had this:

```
(defun what-face (pos)
    (interactive "d")
        (let ((face (or (get-char-property (point) 'read-face-name)
            (get-char-property (point) 'face))))
    (if face (message "Face: %s" face) (message "No face at %d" pos))))
```

Comment: Duh, forgot it wasn't bundled with Emacs.  May I put the source in my answer w/attribution? :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug in the `what-face' code: the function takes "pos" as an argument but then doesn't use it when getting the face -- instead it uses "(point)", even though the message later *claims* pos in the "No face at %d" case.

Comment: This would be better placed as a comment on that answer.

Comment: Even better if it had a fix... +1 for spotting it anyway

Answer (score 0):

I tried [@tray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1242366/13772015) function but it didn't work, [@thedz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1242415/13772015) definition does work:

```lisp
(defun what-face (pos)
  (interactive "d")
  (let ((face (or (get-char-property (point) 'read-face-name)
                  (get-char-property (point) 'face))))
    (if face (message "Face: %s" face) (message "No face at %d" pos))))
```

After some research I found why:

- `(point)` is a function that returns the value of point as an integer.
- `pos` gets the value returned by `(interactive "d")` which will be the position of point, as an integer.
- `get-char-property` expects a position, in this case given by the function `(point)`.

Answer (score 0):

In emacs-lisp,

```lisp
(face-at-point t)
```

which is what `M-x describe-face` uses.