# Modify face under cursor in Emacs, including on ansi-term

Tags: emacs, ipython, emacs-faces

Is there a way to easily modify the `font-face` under cursor?

For example, the text in blue below is hard to read:

[image]

The above is the output of

```
ipython --color "Linux"
```

running on an `ansi-term` with `tango-dark` in `Emacs 24.1`, i.e.  `(load-theme 'tango-dark t)`

If I run `what-cursor-position` on the image above (described here: [Get font face under cursor in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242352/get-font-face-under-cursor-in-emacs)), I get:

```
             position: 30385 of 30477 (100%), column: 22
            character: / (displayed as /) (codepoint 47, #o57, #x2f)
    preferred charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x2F
               syntax: _    which means: symbol
             category: .:Base, a:ASCII, l:Latin, r:Roman
          buffer code: #x2F
            file code: #x2F (encoded by coding system nil)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    xft:-unknown-DejaVu LGC Sans Mono-bold-normal-normal-*-11-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x12)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: SOLIDUS
  old-name: SLASH
  general-category: Po (Punctuation, Other)
  decomposition: (47) ('/')

There are text properties here:
  face                 (:weight bold :foreground "blue2" :background unspecified)
```

How can I modify this font?

In case you are wondering IPython only supports three color sets:

- `Nocolor`
- `Linux` (the one I am using above)
- `LightBG` (for light backgrounds)

### Update:

I think `font-lock-string-face` is a different face:

[image]

In fact, I think that's not the face that IPython uses to represent strings, but the face that `python-mode` uses to represent strings in a buffer with regular python code (in `tango-dark`) -- see below --.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`M-x customize-face` with your cursor over the particular thing you want to modify. Also available are `set-face-foreground` and `set-face-background` depending on what you want to do (sometimes it's good to change the backing color to make the font easier to see in terminals).

So I checked out IPython as mentioned in my comment below and `ipython.el` does no highlighting of its own. The coloring is all done by using terminal ANSI colors. It's possible in some terminals to change the colors via a `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or whatever your shell is and running it from `M-x term` possibly. Through Emacs itself I cannot see a way of changing it as IPython only has 3 default schemes and no way to specify anything specific as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks, but when I invoke `M-x customize-face` it prompts me with `Customize face (default 'all faces')`. I think `all faces` does not refer to the face under the cursor in my picture above. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user273158 It should be `font-lock-string-face`

Comment: Thanks. Why is emacs not prompting me for that face? Shouldn't that be the one that it asks me by `default`? (i.e. the one under cursor). Also, how do you know that `font-lock-string-face` is specifically the face I have under the cursor?

Comment: @user273158 You'll have to believe me on this one, I'm not sure why your Emacs isn't detecting it correctly, mine works in both terminal and X.

Comment: Thanks Jesus. I have updated the OP with more info about this (see the section `Update`)

Comment: @user273158 I don't use IPython so I'm not sure but I can check for you :)

Comment: @user273158 It seems that ipython does it's own coloring outside of Emacs using ansi-colors. As such I don't think you can modify the colors except to one of the 3 color sets described. I looked through `ipython.el` and found no way to do this :\

Comment: Should I look for a method to keep this blue, and only change the color of the direct character at point?

Comment: @Dualinity He could try `TERM=xterm-mono` to disable ansi color output.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to change the way ansi colors are shown:

```
(defface term-color-red
    '((t (:foreground "#ff0000" :background "#ff0000")))
  "Unhelpful docstring.")
```

Here is the whole bunch:

```
term-color-red
term-color-green
term-color-black
term-color-yellow
term-color-blue
term-color-magenta
term-color-cyan
term-color-white
```

Comment: Thanks sabof. Can I then presume that the text in dark blue that I see in the first picture I posted is `term-color-blue`? Also, does `ansi-term` only support the 9 colors you listed?

Comment: term-color-blue, would be my guess. Yes, to the best of my knowledge it's those 9. If using the above form doesn't work, you could try using customize-face, or adding them to your theme definition.

Comment: I've listed red twice, actually it's 8

Answer (score 1):

Like [sabof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14513118/1225607), I  think the color you are seeing is set by `ansi-term`, and not by Emacs' color theme.

A way to configure these colors consists in setting the `ansi-term-color-vector` variable. Looking at the code in `term.el` helps understanding the meaning of this variable: it contains color specifications for the 8 [ansi color escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors):

```lisp
(defvar ansi-term-color-vector
  [unspecified "black" "red3" "green3" "yellow3" "blue2"
   "magenta3" "cyan3" "white"])
```

---

Here is my setup (which might suit you since I'm also using a dark Tango theme) :

```lisp
;; ANSI Term colors
(setq ansi-term-color-vector
      [unspecified "#000000" "#b21818" "#18b218" "#BE5F00"
                   "#6D85BA" "#b218b2" "#18b2b2" "#b2b2b2"])
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how can I test/look-up hexadecimal codes from color appearance? (i.e. like a color palette that shows me the hexadecimal code)

Comment: a google search on "html color palette" should give you thousands of results. Here are a few examples: http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html - http://www.colorcombos.com/ - http://fillster.com/colorcodes/colorpalette.html

Comment: I see. Thanks. I didn't know it was a `html` specification. Do you know if there is a way of having `ansi-term` support more colors than just 8?

Comment: As far as I know, there exist only 8 ansi escape codes corresponding to colors (or 16 if you consider normal and bright colors to be different). Please see my edit for a link to the wikipedia article on ansi escape sequences.